# Win32Api USB SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail fail

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, usb

I am attempting to connect to a USB GPS device.  I can successfully connect to the device if I manually create a file via CreateFile WinApi (using the path specified in Device Manager).

However, when I try to select the device through enumeration I fail @ the SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail call.

I have C code that works correctly, but my C# translation does not appear to work correctly.  I have tried many variations with essentially the same results.

**C Code that works**

```
// Get enumerator handle for the specified ClassGuid
HDEVINFO theDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs((GUID*)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_GRMNUSB, NULL, NULL,
    DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_INTERFACEDEVICE);

SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA theInterfaceData;
theInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(theInterfaceData);

// populate theInterfaceData which contains device class information
if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(theDevInfo, NULL, (GUID*)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_GRMNUSB, 0, &theInterfaceData) &&
    GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
{
  gHandle = 0;
  return;
}
// This is normally used to obtain the device path information using theInterfaceData obtained above
bool initialized = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(theDevInfo, &theInterfaceData, NULL, 0, &theBytesReturned, NULL);
// theBytesReturned = 83
theDevDetailData =
(PSP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA)malloc(theBytesReturned);
theDevDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DETAIL_DATA);

bool initialized = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(theDevInfo, &theInterfaceData, theDevDetailData, theBytesReturned, NULL, &theDevInfoData);
```

---

**C#**

```
[DllImport(@"setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Boolean SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
    IntPtr hDevInfo,
    ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData,
    IntPtr deviceInterfaceDetailData,
    UInt32 deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize,
    out UInt32 requiredSize,
    IntPtr deviceInfoData
    );

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
{
    public Int32 cbSize;
    public Guid interfaceClassGuid;
    public Int32 flags;
    private UIntPtr reserved;
}


// Get enumerator handle for the specified ClassGuid
IntPtr theDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref ClassGuid, (DiGetClassFlags.DIGCF_PRESENT | DiGetClassFlags.DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE));

SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DevInterfaceData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
DevInterfaceData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(DevInterfaceData);

initialized = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(theDevInfo, IntPtr.Zero, ref ClassGuid, 0,
        ref DevInterfaceData); 
// I assume The DevInterfaceData is populated correctly as it matches the C Code
// And I've compared the values in memory and they match

uint bytesReturned = 0;
initialized = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(theDevInfo, ref DevInterfaceData, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);
// I expect bytesReturned = 83 and initialized = true which is the value that is returned in the C Code
// Instead the value 162 is returned
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found the problem.

After poking around pinvoke.net, I found the following

```
// build a Device Interface Detail Data structure
 SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA didd = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA();
 if (IntPtr.Size == 8) // for 64 bit operating systems
     didd.cbSize = 8; 
 else  didd.cbSize = 4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize; // for 32 bit systems
```

Changing this in my code allows me to obtain the DevicePath properly.

Reference for those interested.

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail

Comment: No, that corrupts the stack.  Use Marshal.AllocHGlobal() to allocate the buffer with the required size.  The size you got from the first call.

Comment: why/how is the stack corrupted?  Wont the proper memory be marshaled when I make the Win32api call?

Comment: @HansPassant any chance you could explain why the test for `IntPtr.Size` is necessary and we can't rely on the marshaler to get `SizeOf(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)` right? I'm guessing it has to do with padding somehow?

Comment: @Ohad - an old quirk in SetupAPI, it used 1 byte packing in the 32-bit version of Windows.  Corrected to 8 byte packing in 64-bit.  It can be done by the marshaller but you'd have to declare two different structs with different Pack property values.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the quick turnaround! As long as I have to declare two different structs I don't see it as being much better, so I guess I'll stick with this code.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations, it is working.  You'll get a Unicode string, it's twice as long.  And a FALSE return is correct.  You just need to call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() and verify that you got ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.  Your C code is broken, probably because you forgot to initialize theBytesReturned to zero.

Comment: The C code works properly.  It was the C# code that did not work properly.  theBytesReturned is initialized to 0, it's just not shown in the above code as I didn't put the entire function to save space.  I guess the C code returned 83 bytes due to being ASCII, but if the C# code was expecting a UNICODE string, why is it 162 and not 83x2 = 166?

Comment: I don't know, post the strings and I'll tell you why.  There really is a problem with the C code, the function must return FALSE and GetLastError() must return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.  You then know the required buffer size, allocate it and call the function again.

Comment: Oh yes I agree, the first call does return false, there is a second call that I apparently didn't put that is the actually deviceDetailData read.  I'll edit my post to be correct.  Here is the string @"\\?\usb#vid_091e&pid_0003#5&4a03a84&0&5#{2c9c45c2-8e7d-4c08-a12d-816bbae722c0}"