# First call to SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail will always fail with ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER

Tags: vb.net

I'm going little crazy about this and I already spent few hours to find the problem so I guess I need some WinAPI guru here :) I use VB .NET so please be kind :)

Trying to communicate with some USB device and at SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() step, the (first) call to function will fail with ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER. The second call will have non sense now :) The problem is why ? The DeviceInfoTable handle is correct since I use'it in few more functions with success and I tested Err.LastDllError after each call.

The InterfaceDataStructure I presume is also correct since otherways SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces() will fails. I suspect incorrect declarations of dll imports or structure.

```
    If Not SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(DeviceInfoTable, InterfaceDataStructure, Nothing, 0, StructureSize, Nothing) Then

        ErrorStatus = Err.LastDllError ' <-- always 0x6F8, ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER

    End If
```

Here are declarations

```
       Dim DeviceInfoTable As IntPtr = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
        Dim InterfaceDataStructure As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA = New SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
        Dim InterfaceIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim ErrorStatus As Integer = 0

        Dim DevInfoData As SP_DEVINFO_DATA = New SP_DEVINFO_DATA

        Dim dwRegType As Integer
        Dim dwRegSize As Integer

        Dim DetailedInterfaceDataStructure As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA = New SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
        Dim StructureSize As Integer = 0


    'Structures declarations
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)> _
   Public Structure SP_DEVINFO_DATA
        Public cbSize As UInteger
        Public InterfaceClassGUID As Guid
        Public DevInst As UInteger
        Public Reserved As IntPtr
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)> _
    Public Structure SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
        Public cbSize As UInteger
        Public InterfaceClassGuid As Guid
        Public Flags As UInteger
        Public Reserved As IntPtr
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)> _
    Public Structure SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
        Public cbSize As UInteger
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=256)> Public DevicePath As String
    End Structure

    <DllImport("setupapi.dll",
    CharSet:=CharSet.Auto,
    SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(ByVal hDevInfo As IntPtr,
                                                           ByRef deviceInterfaceData As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA,
                                                           ByRef deviceInterfaceDetailData As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA,
                                                           ByVal deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize As Int32,
                                                           ByRef RequiredSize As Int32,
                                                           ByRef deviceInfo As SP_DEVINFO_DATA) As Boolean
```

Thanks very much in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Not SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(..., Nothing, 0, StructureSize, Nothing)
```

You are struggling with basic VB.NET usage here, the keyword *Nothing* doesn't mean what you hope it does.  What the api function wants you to do is pass a null pointer.  IntPtr.Zero.  That *could* be Nothing, but it is not in this case.  You declared the argument types as structures.  They are **value types**.  Nothing means something else in the case of value types, it means "default value".  So you are actually passing a pointer to a structure here, a structure that's zero initialized.  The function is unhappy about that and tells you so.

You cannot pass IntPtr.Zero when you use these pinvoke declarations.  You can cheat and declare an *overload* of the function, one that uses different argument types.  Like this:

```
<DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
   ByVal hDevInfo As IntPtr,
   ByRef deviceInterfaceData As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA,
   ByVal mustPassIntPtrZero As IntPtr,
   ByVal mustPassZero As Int32,
   ByRef RequiredSize As Int32,
   ByVal mustPassIntPtrZero2 As IntPtr) As Boolean
```

Now you can make the first call to the function:

```
If Not SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(..., IntPtr.Zero, 0, StructureSize, IntPtr.Zero)
```

You should use the returned RequiredSize to allocate memory with Marshal.AllocHGlobal().  Pass the returned pointer as the deviceInterfaceDetailData argument.  Which must now be declared as ByVal IntPtr.  And use Marshal.PtrToStructure() to convert it to the struct after the call.  Yes, Pack is an issue on 64-bit operating systems.

Fix the string problem by declaring the structure with CharSet:=CharSet.Auto so you'll get the Unicode conversion instead of the Ansi conversion.

Comment: The returned `AllocHGlobal` `IntPtr` can't be passed directly as the `deviceInterfaceDetailData` arg- its `cbSize` has to be set first using `Marshal.WriteInt32` (using the size here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9247377/67824). I'm also not sure how to define `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA.DevicePath`. The OP uses `SizeConst=256` but I'm not aware of any docs specifying this limit. The only thing I could come up with is something like `Reflection.Emit` with the correct `SizeConst`, or dropping `PtrToStruct` altogether and parsing the memory using `Marshal.ReadXXX`. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Now I figured out, in fact half working :) Maybe someone can en light me.

At least on VB .NET 2010, the SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() doesn't line NULLs (aka nothing) as parameters, so I had to first pass something dummy:

```
    DetailedInterfaceDataStructure.cbSize = 6

    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(DeviceInfoTable, InterfaceDataStructure, DetailedInterfaceDataStructure, 1000, StructureSize, DevInfoData)
```

The cbSize must be <> 0 and on 32 bit systems must be 6 (4 for DWORD and 2 for null terminated wide string). The 1000 it's just a big number, so SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() won't return even ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER

Now the second pass supposed to get the real stuff:

```
    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(DeviceInfoTable, InterfaceDataStructure, DetailedInterfaceDataStructure, StructureSize, StructureSize, Nothing)
```

Which doesn't return any system error, but path is only a backslash character "\" and this isn't good.... it supposed to be a valid USB path

"\\?\usb#vid_01E5&pid_00A2#5&1d4952dc&0&2#{18d0A210-85D2-........"

Anyone can help me ?...

Answer (score 0):

yes I am struggling with VB since I'm coming from pure C99 and assembler for MCU :) In fact, after few hours of errors I got some snippet in C# that worked like a charm but I had to know why isn't working in VB :) I finally solved, partially like your advices

I overloaded SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() with another one, just to accept a ptr to some unmanaged buffer:

```
<DllImport("setupapi.dll",
 CharSet:=CharSet.Auto,
 SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(ByVal hDevInfo As IntPtr,
                                                       ByRef deviceInterfaceData As SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA,
                                                       ByVal deviceInterfaceDetailData As IntPtr,
                                                       ByVal deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize As Int32,
                                                       ByRef RequiredSize As Int32,
                                                       ByRef deviceInfo As SP_DEVINFO_DATA) As Boolean
End Function

Now the problem was I used ByRef deviceInterfaceDetailData As IntPtr instead of ByVal deviceInterfaceDetailData As IntPtr, was my mistake from VB's quite simple perspective.

Indeed, now I can pass some unmanaged buffer at 2'nd call of SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail()




    Dim PUnmanagedDetailedInterfaceDataStructure As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    PUnmanagedDetailedInterfaceDataStructure = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(StructureSize) 
    DetailedInterfaceDataStructure.cbSize = 6 ' cbSize = 4 bytes for DWORD + 2 bytes for Unicode null terminator
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(DetailedInterfaceDataStructure, PUnmanagedDetailedInterfaceDataStructure, False) ' Copy the contents of the structure, to an unmanaged memory space


    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(DeviceInfoTable, InterfaceDataStructure, PUnmanagedDetailedInterfaceDataStructure, StructureSize, StructureSize, DevInfoData)
```

And this is finally working. I expect some points for struggling :)
I saw a lot of similar threads on internet but none with a complete solve.

Merry Christmas to all