# C# - SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail will get the strange String

Tags: c#, wpf, hid

Recently, I want to use C# to get the HID device. But I meet some trouble.

When I use SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() function, I will get the wrong path.

My code of get path function as below.

```
private string GetDevicePath(IntPtr hDeviceInfo, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devInterfaceData)
    {
        uint nRequiredSize = 0;
        //basically, the first device detailed will return the false... it the really thing.
        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDeviceInfo, ref devInterfaceData, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)0, ref nRequiredSize, IntPtr.Zero))
        {

            ///Declare Sample 3:
            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA oDevInterfaceDetailedData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA();
            //Create Buffer to save the path detailed.
            oDevInterfaceDetailedData.cbSize = 5; //=5

            ///With Sample 3:
            if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDeviceInfo, ref devInterfaceData,ref oDevInterfaceDetailedData, nRequiredSize, ref nRequiredSize, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                //FIXME: Problem 1: The CreateFile will return 123. its means The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
                //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

                ///With Sample 3:
                Log.Text += ("Acutal Path = "+ oDevInterfaceDetailedData.DevicePath + "\n");
                return oDevInterfaceDetailedData.DevicePath;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The question is here: oDevInterfaceDetailedData.DevicePath

The string variable will shows the message as below.

```
Acutal Path = 屜尿楨⍤楶彤㌰て瀦摩ㅟ㐰⌱☶㐱㡡㈶搷〦〦〰⌰㑻ㅤ㕥戵ⴲㅦ昶ㄭ挱ⵦ㠸扣〭㄰ㄱ〱〰㌰細
```

My declare of function/structure as below

```
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    protected static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr lpDeviceInfoSet, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA oInterfaceData, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA lpDeviceInterfaceDetailData, uint nDeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, ref uint nRequiredSize, IntPtr lpDeviceInfoData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    protected static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr lpDeviceInfoSet, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA oInterfaceData, IntPtr lpDeviceInterfaceDetailData, uint nDeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, ref uint nRequiredSize, IntPtr lpDeviceInfoData);[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

    public struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string DevicePath;
    }
```

My platform is 64 bits Windows OS.
I use the VS2017 IDE to build a WPF project in C#.

Does someone could help me to figure out the question is..... Thanks a lot

Comment: My secret decoder ring can turn that into `\\\\?\\hid#vid_03f0&pid_1041#6&14a8627d&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}`.  Looks more like it.  Apply [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode]) to the structure declaration and likewise add CharSet to the [DllImport] declarations.

Comment: ok. I will try the charset.... and what's the secret decoder??  (curious

Answer (score 0):

- You try with codes:

  [DllImport(@"setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

  public static extern Boolean SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
      IntPtr hDevInfo,
      ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData,
      IntPtr deviceInterfaceDetailData,
      UInt32 deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize,
      out UInt32 requiredSize,
      IntPtr deviceInfoData
      );
- Reference for those interested.  [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail)
- [And here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245595/win32api-usb-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetail-fail)

Comment: Hi BillBguyen, I also check the website to design and implement the dllimport. But it seems doesn't work.....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hans Passant.

I finally modify the SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA structure.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string DevicePath;
    }
```

The CharSet need to use ansi instead of auto...